# "The name "X" does not exist in the current context" ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, publish

the class inside the App_Code folder is this as follows;

```
public class Sample
{
    public Sample()
    {
        
    }

    public static void ActionSample()
    {

    }   
}
```

I get an error when I want to call the method of this class. There is no other code.

**For example the code in default.aspx.cs;**

```
using System;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Sample.ActionSample();
    }
}
```

The project is running normally. But when I want to publish, I get an error.

**the error message is;**

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0103  The name 'Sample' does not exist in the current context 4_Default.aspx  C:\Users****\source\repos\MSDN\MSDN\Default.aspx.cs    8   Active

**Why?**

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with the norms of the site. Code and error messages need to be provided as text in the body of the post. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: change from `Debug` to `Release` then try to do a build.  The IDE should show you what's causing the error.

Comment: I added a photo because I couldn't write it in code.
and only debug mode. no release options

Comment: Two of those images are of code. There's no excuse for not pasting the code into the post. The last one is an error message which you should format using the `>` line prefix to quote it. We don't need to see it in the tool window. The English translation is sufficient, and preferred because this is an English-language site. Solution Explorer isn't very helpful.

Comment: Until your post is properly written, you're unlikely to get an answer. If you don't put in the effort that's expected, don't expect anyone else to put in the effort to help you. As it stands, your post is unclear. You need to post a [mre].

Comment: now, I am waiting for your reply. ok?

Comment: You still have not provided a [mcve]. Ideally we could copy your code and paste it into a brand new console app or a tool like [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) and recreate the issue. At a minimum, I'd expect to see relevant namespaces and using statements.

Answer (score -2):

For Clarity, here's the Soru.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;



namespace Soru
{
    partial class Soru
    {
        static Soru()
        {
        }

        public static void Neden()
        {

        }

    }
}
```

And to call it, here's the (form / default.aspx) file

```
namespace Soru
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            Soru.Neden();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tnx u but I can't call static method from new class.

Comment: You don't have to instantiate an instance of a class in order to invoke a static method on the class. That's the whole point of the static modifier. Please make sure you [visit the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static). If you're not 100% confident, then make sure you try out your code on your machine, or using a tool like [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) before posting an answer.

Comment: Your edit has still not improved anything. Making the class static will do nothing to solve the problem. There's no rush to provide an answer. Don't answer until you are 100% sure you have a working solution. If you need more info on the question, then wait until that info is available before providing an answer.

Comment: Thanks once again, I tried this in visual studio on a C# WinForms app. Not what the OP had posted, granted, but it worked on mine, so it's the best pointer I can give. I will bear your comments in mind, I don't want to lead anybody down the wrong path but while I have time, it's an attempt to help while learning myself.

Comment: This still isn't a useful answer. You haven't identified the part of the code that needs to change to solve the problem, you've included extra using statements that aren't necessary but may confuse someone who is seeing them added, and you've got a static constructor for no clear reason. Please just delete your answer, wait for the question to become clear. Once it is clear and you have a clear solution to the problem, then you can attempt an answer. Right now, this isn't helping the situation. I admire your willingness to help, but some tact here will be more effective.

Comment: Thank you once again Mason for the advice. You're correct, I have additional Using statements, which are the default added by Visual Studio. I have included a pointless constructor because the OP had one so I assume they are adding something. I'm not up to speed on the etiquette of Stackoverflow but I believe my answer will help the OP. If I've violated any rules, and I will learn as I go, I won't be as eager to help next time, but surely that is against the whole ethos of Stackoverflow??????

Comment: You haven't violated any rules. However, I'd urge you to be objective and consider the friendly advice I'm trying to pass along. There's a difference between *trying to help* and actually helping. I don't want you to discourage you from helping in the future, rather I want to guide you in what the proper way to go about it is. Wait for the question to become clear before attempting an answer. That's crucial. We don't have a clear problem statement, because we don't have a full [mcve]. We also didn't know the framework.

Comment: Now it's clear that it's ASP.NET Web Forms, yet your answer is geared towards Windows Forms. For a beginner in C#, this can be quite confusing. I also pointed out a few things about the code you provided to help you see how they can be confusing for someone struggling with a compiler error. This isn't meant to be critical feedback of you, but instead to help understand the best way to help others out on this site, so we can keep this as a high quality resource without a lot of less useful content to sift through. I appreciate the effort, just hoping we can focus it into a more useful direction

Comment: I fully understand and appreciate your point of view, thank you. I'm here to learn as much as the next person and will take them into consideration on future posts.